# Views not responding on action when added from framework

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, autolayout

I created a simple framework for my custom view. I want from my view to be reusable across multiple applications. The problem is that when I change constraints in the project, the view is not responding to any action like hitting the button, on entering text in textField. I am guessing that the problems lays in `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`.

Let's suppose that I have a framework like bellow:

```
public class CustomView: UIView {


public let customButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
    
    return button
}()

public var buttonWidth: CGFloat = 100

public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initConstraints()
}


func initConstraints(){
    addSubview(customButton)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        customButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 80),
        customButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
        customButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonWidth)

    ])
}

public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}}
```

When successfully added the framework to the project, I need to change the position of the view. From center to be more on top. I'm creating a class

```
class FrameworkView: UIView {

let customButton: CustomView = {
    let cusomView = CustomView()
    cusomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return cusomView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initConst()
}

func initConst()  {
    
    addSubview(customButton)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        customButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100),
        customButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 25),
        customButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -25),
    ])
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}}
```

Everything looks ok when I add the view to ViewController.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    let demo = FrameworkView(frame: view.frame)

    view.addSubview(demo)
    
    
    demo.customButton.customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}


@objc func tap(_ sender: UIButton){
    print("Test")
}
```

Unfortunately, the button is not responding to the action. The same with other views like textFields, TextViews, etc.
I can't figure out how to solve this bug. I guess that something is wrong with the subviews and constraints.
Thank you for any kind of help.
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the height of `CustomView` (the one that is a subview of `FrameworkView`) is ambiguous. This causes it to not be displayed. But because the frame of the `UIButton` is not ambiguous, it is still displayed. I think this is possibly why the click events didn't go through to the button - the frame of the button's superview, `CustomView` is ambiguous.

The reason why the height is ambiguous is because you seem to have forgotten a bottom constraint:

```
// in FrameworkView
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    customButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100),
    customButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 25),
    customButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -25),
    // your forgot this!
    customButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -100)
])
```

If you add the bottom constraint then the button will work.

---

Rather than creating another view that wraps `CustomView`, you can consider modifying `CustomView` so that it exposes a `topConstraint` property (since all you seem to want to do is to move the button downwards a little):

```
public class CustomView: UIView {

    public var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    ...

    private func initConstraints(){
        addSubview(customButton)
        topConstraint = customButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 80)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            topConstraint,
            customButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            customButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonWidth)

        ])
    }
```

Now you don't need `FrameworkView`, can set `topConstraint.constant` to move the button downwards.